# django query a model that has a foreign key, checking a property of that foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many, django-queryset

Let's say I have two models,  **model_0**  and  **model_1**

**model_0**  is defined as following

```
def model_0:
    ...
    foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(model_1)
    ...
```

and **model_1**

```
def model_1:
    ...
    random_property = models.Charfield()
    ...
```

**model_1**  is a foreign key (could be a manytomany or whatever) in **model_0**

How can I perform a query in the **model_1** objects checking the property of the **model_0**

Something like `model_0.objects.filter(model_0.random_property="Something")`

I know that you can easily perform queries with the model like `model_0.objectsl.filter(model_0="Instance of model 0")`

But I haven't seen any way to check a specific property of that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look "through" a relation with double underscores (`__`), so you can filter with:

```
model_0.objects.filter(foreign_key__random_property='Something')
```

This will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT model_0.*
FROM model_0
LEFT OUTER JOIN model_1 ON model_1.id = model_0.foreign_key_id
WHERE model_1.random_property = 'Something'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is done by double underscore in your case it would look like this `model_0.objects.filter(model_1__random_property="Something")`
Try reading the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/). They are really helpful.